# How Stack Overflow recognizes Ukrainian border in last survey - simple mistake or support of Russian annexation of Crimea?

Tags: support

I got a [Twitter update](https://twitter.com/andrew_gubskiy/status/1267181432348332032?fbclid=IwAR2H_v1c-OLn6FH4NVZieUKH_B1BAbiR5jGS7Qd5XVvrC8zbMWW3MmgUVgQ) from Andrew Gubskiy:
[map](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EZXub_DWAAML1TV?format=jpg&name=small).

It looks like Stack Overflow supports the Russian annexation of Crimea in the last survey. Please fix your [map](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#geography).

Comment: It's already been asked for on twitter and got a response (from Nick saying it'll get looked into), I fail to see what bringing it here will gain

Comment: @Nick because Meta - not twitter - is the proper place to track SO issues.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I didn't say it wasn't, it should have been posted here in the first place, I still fail to see *what can be gained from cross posting it here*. And regardless, this isn't something that can ever be resolved happily. Whether or not SO "support" the russian annexation of crimea is totally irrelevant, they administer it, they provide power, it uses the russian ruble... the list goes on, and they have done for 6 years. People can dislike the annexation as much as they want, that doesn't make the map factually incorrect. This is a no win situation

Comment: I doubt a Stack Overflow employee went through and hand-drew the borders of the world's countries... or maybe they did, because they did a crap job with Hawai'i; I was born on an island they don't even show! I want my money back!

Comment: @Nick "It's already been asked for on twitter and got a response (from Nick saying it'll get looked into)" I'm a bit confused. Is Nick looking into it? Are there two Nicks?

Comment: @Trilarion Nick Craver, not me :p

Comment: The map doesn't include Singapore either

Comment: The map is obviously not meant to be accurate. It's drawn heavily stylized and with obvious attempts to simplify. Extracting geopolitical messages from this is just silly.

Comment: @CodyGray Including some territory with one or another country is not a simplification though. Leaving Crimea out completely would have been a simplification. It might just be a mistake but in the end SO is responsible for the maps they draw, I think.

Comment: Sure. Not saying it's unreasonable to file bugs against the map's accuracy. But some of the comments (and especially Twitter) are going too far, drawing geopolitical conclusions from a map that clearly wasn't drawn by a cartographer, and I think that's unreasonable. @Trilarion

Comment: @CodyGray It's impossible to completely separate politics from everyday life, if only just because in a possible reply SO would have to make a conscious decision, or by not replying they are also sending a statement. That's why I think it is not just a bug that can be fixed and everyone is happy. Haven't read the Twitter comments.

Comment: Did Nick look into it? What was the result? Did he maybe post on Twitter? Or was there no further reply (which would also be kind of an answer I would say)?